# Prevent screen output heredoc

Tags: php, bash, output, echo, heredoc

I'm writing a bash shell script whose purpose is to create a php skeleton for new projects.

To create certain php documents within the newly created directory structure, I'm using HEREDOCs with tons of codelines..

```
sudo tee $projectname/www/index.php <<- EOF | > null
<?php           

ob_start();

require_once 'inc/header.inc';

ob_end_flush();
?>
EOF

## Create header.inc
sudo tee $projectname/www/inc/header.inc <<- EOF 1>&2

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
....
EOF
```

The problem is: 
All HEREDOC lines are echoed to the screen. That is really not what I want, it looks very messy.
So, I tried to issue this, by redirecting output to `null`and `/dev/null`. Unfortunately without success.

Research:

- [Preventing output from commands in Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099466/preventing-output-from-commands-in-batch)
- [Echo in heredoc / nowdoc syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523718/echo-in-heredoc-nowdoc-syntax)
- [Outputting variable within Heredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364595/outputting-variable-within-heredoc)
- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your redirect syntax is incorrect.  Lose the `|`

```
sudo tee $projectname/www/index.php <<-EOF >/dev/null
```

The other redirection attempt you have `1>&2` would merely redirect standard output to standard error, which (normally) lands on your screen in the end anyway.  It's useful, but not for you are trying to accomplish.

It would be better hygiene to create the project as yourself and use a separate (version control and) deployment infrastructure to publish a production version only when you have something of suitable quality and completeness, though.  Then you don't need `sudo`, and then you don't need `tee`.

```
cat <<-EOF >$projectname/www/index.php
```

The `sudo tee file >/dev/null` trick is a bit of an antipattern to enable you to write files like with `cat` when you are using `sudo`.

Comment: @Etan Reisner Thanks for your suggestions! The <<-EOF >/dev/null part solved the output problem!

Comment: FWIW, I prefer `sudo dd of=/path/to/file <<-EOF` to the `sudo tee` hack, but obviously avoiding the sudo in the first place is better.

Comment: @kzpm: If the webserver can execute a sudo, then you might as well just give it write permissions to a directory; obviously, it has them if it needs them. Better solutions exist but that would be a different question, and arguably better asked on a sysadmin QA site. Anyway, I still prefer `sudo dd` to `sudo tee` (because you don't have to deal with discarding the output), but tastes vary.

Comment: @rici Thanks for your observation rici, I will try 'dd'. Never thought one could use dd also for this specific purpose.